# Cross Account Cloudtrail log transfer through Cloudwatch and Kinesis data stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-cloudtrail

I am using Cloudwatch subscriptions to send over cloudtrail log of one account into another. The Account receiving the logs has a Kinesis data stream which receives the logs from the cloudwatch subscription and invokes the standard lambda function provided by AWS to parse and store the logs to an S3 bucket of the log receiver account.
The log files getting written to s3 bucket are in the form of :

```
{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"AA:i-096379450e69ed082","arn":"arn:aws:sts::34502sdsdsd:assumed-role/RDSAccessRole/i-096379450e69ed082","accountId":"34502sdsdsd","accessKeyId":"ASIAVAVKXAXXXXXXXC","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKDDDDD","arn":"arn:aws:iam::3450291sdsdsd:role/RDSAccessRole","accountId":"345029asasas","userName":"RDSAccessRole"},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2021-04-27T04:38:52Z"},"ec2RoleDelivery":"2.0"}},"eventTime":"2021-04-27T07:24:20Z","eventSource":"ssm.amazonaws.com","eventName":"ListInstanceAssociations","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"188.208.227.188","userAgent":"aws-sdk-go/1.25.41 (go1.13.15; linux; amd64) amazon-ssm-agent/","requestParameters":{"instanceId":"i-096379450e69ed082","maxResults":20},"responseElements":null,"requestID":"a5c63b9d-aaed-4a3c-9b7d-a4f7c6b774ab","eventID":"70de51df-c6df-4a57-8c1e-0ffdeb5ac29d","readOnly":true,"resources":[{"accountId":"34502914asasas","ARN":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:3450291asasas:instance/i-096379450e69ed082"}],"eventType":"AwsApiCall","managementEvent":true,"eventCategory":"Management","recipientAccountId":"345029149342"}
{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPKZ25XXXX:AmazonMWAA-airflow","arn":"arn:aws:sts::3450291asasas:assumed-role/dev-1xdcfd/AmazonMWAA-airflow","accountId":"34502asasas","accessKeyId":"ASIAVAVKXAXXXXXXX","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPKZXXXXX","arn":"arn:aws:iam::345029asasas:role/service-role/AmazonMWAA-dlp-dev-1xdcfd","accountId":"3450291asasas","userName":"dlp-dev-1xdcfd"},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2021-04-27T07:04:08Z"}},"invokedBy":"airflow.amazonaws.com"},"eventTime":"2021-04-27T07:23:46Z","eventSource":"logs.amazonaws.com","eventName":"CreateLogStream","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"airflow.amazonaws.com","userAgent":"airflow.amazonaws.com","errorCode":"ResourceAlreadyExistsException","errorMessage":"The specified log stream already exists","requestParameters":{"logStreamName":"scheduler.py.log","logGroupName":"dlp-dev-DAGProcessing"},"responseElements":null,"requestID":"40b48ef9-fc4b-4d1a-8fd1-4f2584aff1e9","eventID":"ef608d43-4765-4a3a-9c92-14ef35104697","readOnly":false,"eventType":"AwsApiCall","apiVersion":"20140328","managementEvent":true,"eventCategory":"Management","recipientAccountId":"3450291asasas"}
```

The problem with this type of log lines is that Athena is not able to Parse these log lines and I am not able to query the logs using Athena.

I tried modifying the blueprint lambda function to save the log file as a standard JSON result which would make it easy for Athena to parse the files.

Eg:

```
{'Records': ['{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPBRW2S3TAF:i-096379450e69ed082","arn":"arn:aws:sts::345029149342:assumed-role/RightslineRDSAccessRole/i-096379450e69ed082","accountId":"345029149342","accessKeyId":"ASIAVAVKXAKPBL653UOC","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPXXXXXXX","arn":"arn:aws:iam::34502asasas:role/RDSAccessRole","accountId":"345029asasas","userName":"RDSAccessRole"},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2021-04-27T04:38:52Z"},"ec2RoleDelivery":"2.0"}},"eventTime":"2021-04-27T07:24:20Z","eventSource":"ssm.amazonaws.com","eventName":"ListInstanceAssociations","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"188.208.227.188","userAgent":"aws-sdk-go/1.25.41 (go1.13.15; linux; amd64) amazon-ssm-agent/","requestParameters":{"instanceId":"i-096379450e69ed082","maxResults":20},"responseElements":null,"requestID":"a5c63b9d-aaed-4a3c-9b7d-a4f7c6b774ab","eventID":"70de51df-c6df-4a57-8c1e-0ffdeb5ac29d","readOnly":true,"resources":[{"accountId":"3450291asasas","ARN":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:34502asasas:instance/i-096379450e69ed082"}],"eventType":"AwsApiCall","managementEvent":true,"eventCategory":"Management","recipientAccountId":"345029asasas"}]}
```

The modified code for Blueprint Lambda function that I looks like:

```
    import base64
    import json
    import gzip
    from io import BytesIO
    import boto3
    
    
    def transformLogEvent(log_event):
       
        return log_event['message'] + '\n'
    
    
    def processRecords(records):
        for r in records:
            data = base64.b64decode(r['data'])
            striodata = BytesIO(data)
            with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=striodata, mode='r') as f:
                data = json.loads(f.read())
    
            recId = r['recordId']
            
            if data['messageType'] == 'CONTROL_MESSAGE':
                yield {
                    'result': 'Dropped',
                    'recordId': recId
                }
            elif data['messageType'] == 'DATA_MESSAGE':
                result = {}
                result["Records"] = {}
                events = []
                for e in data['logEvents']:
                    events.append(e["message"])
                result["Records"] = events
                print(result)
                
                if len(result) <= 6000000:
                    yield {
                        'data': result,
                        'result': 'Ok',
                        'recordId': recId
                    }
                else:
                    yield {
                        'result': 'ProcessingFailed',
                        'recordId': recId
                    }
            else:
                yield {
                    'result': 'ProcessingFailed',
                    'recordId': recId
                }
    
    
    def putRecordsToFirehoseStream(streamName, records, client, attemptsMade, maxAttempts):
        failedRecords = []
        codes = []
        errMsg = ''
        # if put_record_batch throws for whatever reason, response['xx'] will error out, adding a check for a valid
        # response will prevent this
        response = None
        try:
            response = client.put_record_batch(DeliveryStreamName=streamName, Records=records)
        except Exception as e:
            failedRecords = records
            errMsg = str(e)
    
        # if there are no failedRecords (put_record_batch succeeded), iterate over the response to gather results
        if not failedRecords and response and response['FailedPutCount'] > 0:
            for idx, res in enumerate(response['RequestResponses']):
                # (if the result does not have a key 'ErrorCode' OR if it does and is empty) => we do not need to re-ingest
                if 'ErrorCode' not in res or not res['ErrorCode']:
                    continue
    
                codes.append(res['ErrorCode'])
                failedRecords.append(records[idx])
    
            errMsg = 'Individual error codes: ' + ','.join(codes)
    
        if len(failedRecords) > 0:
            if attemptsMade + 1 < maxAttempts:
                print('Some records failed while calling PutRecordBatch to Firehose stream, retrying. %s' % (errMsg))
                putRecordsToFirehoseStream(streamName, failedRecords, client, attemptsMade + 1, maxAttempts)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Could not put records after %s attempts. %s' % (str(maxAttempts), errMsg))
    
    
    def putRecordsToKinesisStream(streamName, records, client, attemptsMade, maxAttempts):
        failedRecords = []
        codes = []
        errMsg = ''
        # if put_records throws for whatever reason, response['xx'] will error out, adding a check for a valid
        # response will prevent this
        response = None
        try:
            response = client.put_records(StreamName=streamName, Records=records)
        except Exception as e:
            failedRecords = records
            errMsg = str(e)
    
        # if there are no failedRecords (put_record_batch succeeded), iterate over the response to gather results
        if not failedRecords and response and response['FailedRecordCount'] > 0:
            for idx, res in enumerate(response['Records']):
                # (if the result does not have a key 'ErrorCode' OR if it does and is empty) => we do not need to re-ingest
                if 'ErrorCode' not in res or not res['ErrorCode']:
                    continue
    
                codes.append(res['ErrorCode'])
                failedRecords.append(records[idx])
    
            errMsg = 'Individual error codes: ' + ','.join(codes)
    
        if len(failedRecords) > 0:
            if attemptsMade + 1 < maxAttempts:
                print('Some records failed while calling PutRecords to Kinesis stream, retrying. %s' % (errMsg))
                putRecordsToKinesisStream(streamName, failedRecords, client, attemptsMade + 1, maxAttempts)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Could not put records after %s attempts. %s' % (str(maxAttempts), errMsg))
    
    
    def createReingestionRecord(isSas, originalRecord):
        if isSas:
            return {'data': base64.b64decode(originalRecord['data']), 'partitionKey': originalRecord['kinesisRecordMetadata']['partitionKey']}
        else:
            return {'data': base64.b64decode(originalRecord['data'])}
    
    
    def getReingestionRecord(isSas, reIngestionRecord):
        if isSas:
            return {'Data': reIngestionRecord['data'], 'PartitionKey': reIngestionRecord['partitionKey']}
        else:
            return {'Data': reIngestionRecord['data']}
    
    
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        print(event)
        isSas = 'sourceKinesisStreamArn' in event
        streamARN = event['sourceKinesisStreamArn'] if isSas else event['deliveryStreamArn']
        region = streamARN.split(':')[3]
        streamName = streamARN.split('/')[1]
        records = list(processRecords(event['records']))
        projectedSize = 0
        dataByRecordId = {rec['recordId']: createReingestionRecord(isSas, rec) for rec in event['records']}
        putRecordBatches = []
        recordsToReingest = []
        totalRecordsToBeReingested = 0
    
        for idx, rec in enumerate(records):
            if rec['result'] != 'Ok':
                continue
            projectedSize += len(rec['data']) + len(rec['recordId'])
            # 6000000 instead of 6291456 to leave ample headroom for the stuff we didn't account for
            if projectedSize > 6000000:
                totalRecordsToBeReingested += 1
                recordsToReingest.append(
                    getReingestionRecord(isSas, dataByRecordId[rec['recordId']])
                )
                records[idx]['result'] = 'Dropped'
                del(records[idx]['data'])
    
            # split out the record batches into multiple groups, 500 records at max per group
            if len(recordsToReingest) == 500:
                putRecordBatches.append(recordsToReingest)
                recordsToReingest = []
    
        if len(recordsToReingest) > 0:
            # add the last batch
            putRecordBatches.append(recordsToReingest)
    
        # iterate and call putRecordBatch for each group
        recordsReingestedSoFar = 0
        if len(putRecordBatches) > 0:
            client = boto3.client('kinesis', region_name=region) if isSas else boto3.client('firehose', region_name=region)
            for recordBatch in putRecordBatches:
                if isSas:
                    putRecordsToKinesisStream(streamName, recordBatch, client, attemptsMade=0, maxAttempts=20)
                else:
                    putRecordsToFirehoseStream(streamName, recordBatch, client, attemptsMade=0, maxAttempts=20)
                recordsReingestedSoFar += len(recordBatch)
                print('Reingested %d/%d records out of %d' % (recordsReingestedSoFar, totalRecordsToBeReingested, len(event['records'])))
        else:
            print('No records to be reingested')
    
        return {"records": records}
```

My end goal is to store the result on S3 as JSON so that it can be queried easily with Athena.

the line where the transformation is happening is:

```
elif data['messageType'] == 'DATA_MESSAGE':
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you facing any issues while querying the example that you have provided in your question ? What exactly you need with respect to Athena processing a JSON file ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes, Athena is not able to parse the log lines mentioned in the beginning of my question. To overcome that, I am modifying the lambda code to write the log file as JSON object so that it can be parsed with Athena and thus query the data.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy If there is a way to parse the Log lines at the top, using Athena, then I am good with that too. The only reason for doing the conversion is that Athena is not able to pick it up as a standard format.

Comment: Have you tried the DDL from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html#create-cloudtrail-table-partition-projection ? If you are not doing any changes you should be able to query it using this defintion. Update your question with errors you receive when this DDL is used?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes I have used it. It does create the table but upon querying, no result gets populated.

Comment: Can you do "show create table <table-name>" and update your question with the DDL used/generated?